# get title from component jlabel in a jtabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtabbedpane

### i need to get text from select tab Jlabel (tabLabel in the code) for using it in the program

```
public void add() {
    final JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.add(new JButton("kash"));
    JPanel tab = new JPanel();
    tab.setOpaque(false);
    JLabel tabLabel = new JLabel("Tab " + (++tabCounter));
    JButton tabCloseButton = new JButton(closeXIcon);
    tabCloseButton.setPreferredSize(closeButtonSize);
    tabCloseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int closeTabNumber = tabbedPane.indexOfComponent(content);
            tabbedPane.removeTabAt(closeTabNumber);
        }
    });
    tab.add(tabLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    tab.add(tabCloseButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
    tabbedPane.addTab("aaa", content);
    tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(tabbedPane.getTabCount() - 1, tab);
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add `mouseClicked(MouseEvent)` event to your `tabLabel` and write this function `tabLabel.getText()` in event function.

[See how to add MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: thx,the problem is that i have many tab each have it tablabel and they are opened from an click action on Jlist item where they also get text to display i don't need to click on the label but to get text from it when i press for example a button in the tab panel

Comment: The component clicking on which you want text of tablabel, add mouseevent to that component and write tablabel.getText() in that event. For example if a button is pressed and at that time you want the text of tablabel then add tablabel.getText() function in the action event of that button.